# Progressbar for batch command execution

Tags: python, progress-bar

I have the below code that executes a list of commands, held in command_resp on the system

```
for x in command_resp:  
        x=x.replace("\\","")
        print(x)
        os.system(x)
```

I need to print a progressbar for each command. Let's say that the follwoing commands are being passed:

```
uname -a
nmap x.x.x.x
```

The requirement is to print progressbar commenting on the status of each of the providedjob

Answer (score 0):

Since os.system waits for the process you can calculate the percentage from the len of the list and the index. If you want a neat progressbar you can checkout:
https://github.com/WoLpH/python-progressbar

```
for i, x in enumerate(command_resp):  
    x=x.replace("\\","")
    print(x)
    os.system(x)
    print("job {0} of {1} completed".format(i, len(command_resp)))
    print("{0} % completed".format(i/ len(command_resp)))
```

Comment: also I used progressbar but it gives results at the end of all the commands, not after completing one

Comment: Improved the answer to this.

i=0
 for x in command_resp: 
  x=x.replace("\\","")
  i=i+1
  print("\n")
  print(x)
  os.system(x)
  print("\n")
  print("[*] job {0} of {1} completed".format(i, len(command_resp)))
  print("\n")
  print("[*] {0} % completed".format((i)*(100/count)))

still no progressbar

Comment: fixed the parens it should work now, for progressbar never used myself mor of a suggestion